# Representing data-structure in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, numpy, data-structures

What's the best way to represent this data-structure in python:

```
[{'x': 230, 'y': 50}, {'x': 350, 'y': 50}, {'x': 410, 'y': 50}]
```

It's not json, it's something else, sorry for my stupidity, I'm searching various python tutorials, but can't figure out if it's some structure that can be easily loaded like numpy.load or json.loads, because when I try validating that structure as JSON, it says invalid json...

Comment: Well that is a list of dictionaries, what do you want to do with that data?

Comment: It's not JSON, but it easily could be made as such. `json.dumps()` would suffice to serialize it. Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: load/parse it into dictionary of x/y coordinates...

Comment: But it already _is_ that. It's a list of dictionaries. Where does JSON come into this?

Comment: `json.dumps()` converts a JSON object to a string, while `json.loads` converts a string to a JSON object - what do you want to do with this? How are you trying to validate it?

Comment: @roganjosh ok, so how do I access value of second x ?

Comment: `my_list[1]['x']`....

Comment: Your comments under the answers are confusing me as to your confusion :) it's 100% a valid python structure already. It is a list, and each element in that list is a _dictionary_. There is _no_ need to strip any characters or anything. Access the list by index and then get values by _key_.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to load it from file, change something, and put back in file...

Comment: And what format of file is it? Maybe you need `ast.literal_eval()`. We're chasing our tails on both sides of the problem here. These are details missing from your question.

Comment: csv file with that data-structure for one of it's columns... I have loaded it and printed sucessfully, then was able to eval above and got some dictionary structure... Now trying to change something and put back.

Comment: If the source is a `csv` file, then you need to show the file, and show how you load it.  What you show is a Python structure, a list of dictionaries.  A `csv` file contains text.  A `JSON` expression is also a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of three dictionaries (mappings of keys to values) and it works like this:

```
>>> dicts = [{'x': 230, 'y': 50}, {'x': 350, 'y': 50}, {'x': 410, 'y': 50}]
>>> dicts[0]
{'x': 230, 'y': 50}
>>> dicts[0]['x']
230
>>> dicts[2]['y']
50
```

Since all the dictionaries share the same keys (`'x'` and `'y'`) in your example you can interpret them as *records*.

A neat way to represent these records is with a `pandas.DataFrame`, which has a table-like printout.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(dicts)
     x   y
0  230  50
1  350  50
2  410  50
```

---

If you have a *string*

```
>>> s = "[{'x': 230, 'y': 50}, {'x': 350, 'y': 50}, {'x': 410, 'y': 50}]"
```

you can evaluate it safely with `ast.literal_eval`.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(s)
[{'x': 230, 'y': 50}, {'x': 350, 'y': 50}, {'x': 410, 'y': 50}]
```

Comment: I have actually loaded above code with dicts = eval( another variable with that string)...

Comment: @AleksandarPavić consider `ast.literal_eval`, it's the save version of `eval` for literals like strings, lists, dicts, ...

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a list of dictionaries.

```
myList = []

dict1 = {'x': 230, 'y': 50}
dict2 = {'x': 350, 'y': 50}
dict3 = {'x': 410, 'y': 50}

myList.append(dict1)
myList.append(dict2)
myList.append(dict3)
```

Comment: But  I can't just something.load it? I need to do string parser for it? to break on 

} , { and append it?